# Definition of momentum-entangled particles

Tags: momentum, quantum-entanglement, subatomic

When we can say that two particle are momentum entangled ? I just read an article where it's said that two momentum entangled particles share the same momentum value in opposite directions no matter how far they are when it's provided a measurament
...It's a correct description?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article?

Comment: @KyleKanos http://www.mtnmath.com/whatrh/node73.html